# Compare two time in java

Tags: java, date, netbeans-7

I need to compare two time string which i have entered.. I am able to do it for date but for time i am unable to do it. Please find below the code I tried :

My requirement is.. when i check the `Lower` variable as `"<<Current Time>>"` I need to fetch the current time of the system and compare with the `Upper` Variable which is also has a String Time..

```
    Date T1 = new Date();
    Date T2 = new Date();
    String temp_Time = "",Upper="";

    try{
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
        df.setLenient(false);
        System.out.println("Gng to Parse");
        String Lower = " <<Current Time>> ";
        if(Lower.equalsIgnoreCase(" <<Current Time>> ")){
            temp_Time = df.format(T1);
            System.out.println("Formatted : "+temp_Time);    
            **//Here I get the time in format i specified.**    
            T1 = df.parse(temp_Time); 
            // **when i parse, the time format changes and prints "Thu Jan 01 13:24:40 IST 1970"**
            System.out.println("T1 after parsed "+T1);
            T2 = df.parse(Upper);
        } else {
            T1 = df.parse(Lower);
            T2 = df.parse(Upper);                    
        }
        if (T1.after(T2) || T1.equals(T2)) {                    
            System.out.println("Time after || equal");                    
            System.out.println("Upper Time should be greater than Lower Date");    
        } else{
            System.out.println("Else of after ");
        }

    }catch(ParseException p) {
        System.out.println("Time Fields should be in mentioned format "+T1);
    }
 }
```

Comment: You should share the value of `format` and `temp_Time` to make it possible to find the problem.

Comment: What output do you get?

Comment: I don't get the question. If you need current time, you could use System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Well new Date() also has the current time.

Comment: Your failure to follow Java conventions in naming variables with initial lowercase makes your code confusing. Also makes me wonder if you have not yet grasped the basics of Java programming.

Comment: @Sebastian @keuleJ @Basil Bourque Assume `format = "HH:mm:ss"`.. this format will change according to the user request and i need the current time in the format i ask. I am able to get the time `temp_Time = df.format(T1);` till here it prints  `13:24:40` but since this is a `String` i cant use it to compare so i `parse` it  `T1 = df.parse(Lower);`.. At this time it changes and prints `Thu Jan 01 13:24:40 IST 1970`..and i am unable to compare.